# Hive query file execution is failing through oozie

Tags: hive, oozie

I have an hive query file which is having an UDF function. When I ran this query file using "hive -f myqfile.q", it is executing properly and the data is populated in my final table.

But when then same query file is running through the oozie work flow execution, it is failing with the below error message,

```
FAILED: SemanticException: [Error: 10014]: Line: 29:17 Wrong arguments '"start"': No method matching for class com.abc.xyz.hive.udf.GetRowKeyRange with (string, string, string, string). Possible choices: _FUNC_(string, string, string, string, string)
Intercepting System.exit(10014)
Failing Oozie Launcher, Main class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.HiveMain], exit code [10014]
```

In the above error message "start" is the value for one of the parameter for my hive udf.

Jar path which is present the q file is proper (manual execution is working), and the hive udf name is created in side q file, and the class com.abc.xyz.hive.udf.GetRowKeyRange is having evaluate method with only 4 parameters.

I am not sure how this error is coming up, I tried to figure out, at the end I couldn't figure out the reason for this. Can some one help me on this.

Comment: is your oozie wokring?I mean anyother jobs running sucessfully on oozie?show your properties file and xml file. you may try with hue if you have .

Comment: yes, there are many oozie jobs running on this cluster, only the job which is having the above udf invocation is failing.

Answer (score 1):

Is the .jar containing this UDF also sitting on HDFS?  Oozie might not be able to follow the jar path if it is local.

Comment: Yes, the jar which is added in the query file is pointing to local path not the hdfs path. But I have another oozie job which execute query file having an udf with the jar pointing to local and that is executing with out an issue.

Comment: more over, if it is expecting the jar in hdfs, then add jar should fail, but that is passes and temporary function is also created successfully. So that will not be the issue.